# Amazon 600000 General SSLEngine error

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-redshift, sql-workbench-j

I am having an odd error connecting to Redshift using SQL Workbench/J. When I try logging in I get an `Amazon 600000 General SSLEngine problem.` Now I made sure that `=com.amazon.redshift.ssl.NonValidatingFactory`  was added but I am pretty sure that this is only related to 500150 error. Also what is odd is that I am able to sign into other nodes on our system just fine. In addition my coworkers are able to sign in no problem with same credentials without this error. Nobody seems to know how to proceed from here so I am reaching out to you guys. Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had to replace old `cacerts` with one that reflects the Redshift certificate.
`cacerts` location on Mac:

`/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security`

Helpful link from AWS: [Configure Security Options for Connections](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/connecting-ssl-support.html)